# How to divide a dataframe column by 3 but skip division based on another column contents

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, dplyr

I want to divide both numeric columns by 3 but not the third character column.

current dataframe:

```
col1   col2   col3
100    10     cat
200    20     dog
300    30     NA

desired:
col1   col2   col3
10      1     cat
20      2     dog
300     30     NA
```

my current code that isn't based on col3:

```
DB <- BD %>% mutate(Col1=Col1/3) %>% mutate(Col2s=Col2/3)
```

Please help with a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-3), list(~ifelse(!is.na(col3), ./10, .)))

#  col1 col2 col3
#1   10    1  cat
#2   20    2  dog
#3  300   30 <NA>
```

Comment: `mutate_at` is being replaced by `across`, so maybe `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ifelse(!is.na(col3), . / 10,.)))` is better

Comment: grouah I realized your solution is fine but how would it work if there are some other numeric columns that I dont want divided?

Comment: then it won't be useful except if you have a couple of cols to exclude, then you could write something like `where(is.numeric)[-c(var6,var7)]` though i've not tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R.

```
no <- !is.na(dat$col3)
num <- sapply(dat, is.numeric)
dat[na, num] <- dat[na, num]/10
dat
#   col1 col2 col3
# 1   10    1  cat
# 2   20    2  dog
# 3  300   30 <NA>
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="col1   col2   col3
100    10     cat
200    20     dog
300    30     NA")
```

Answer (score 0):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-col3) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(!is.na(col3), value / 3, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(col3, names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can directly do the assignment if we have a logical index

```
dat1[1:2][!is.na(dat1$col3),] <- dat1[1:2, !is.na(dat1$col3)]/10
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[is.na(col3), (1:2) := .SD/10, .SDcols = 1:2]
```